# Permission denied on Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, permissions, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running pipeline job with this pipeline script

```groovy
node {
    stage ('Prepare Environment') {
      checkout scm
      sh 'npm install'
    }
    stage('Build') {
      sh 'docker-compose --verbose up -d'
    }
}
```

and there is an error on `docker-compose`

```
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/var/lib/jenkins/.docker/config.json', '/var/lib/jenkins/.dockercfg']
docker.auth.find_config_file: No config file found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 121, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 40, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 118, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 93, in get_client
  File "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 177, in version
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 191, in _get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
  File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
  File "site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

Also I've tried to follow this command in same machine with `jenkins` user in the same directory, it's work fine with no error.

Comment: From which directory you tried from node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem there is problem with jenkins job executor don't reload shell permission even I've restart jenkins with `/restart` multiple times.

But restart jenkins deamon using `systemctl restart jenkins` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a permission problem, maybe your docker-compose.yml file (or the binary file) is readable only by jenkins user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

And yes, it is permission problem but it won't work even I've made jenkins user able to read docker-compose.yml, as I  mention in the question that **I can run these command in shell using jenkins user** 

It seem there is problem with jenkins job executor itself.

By the way, I've fix this problem below.